# Construct a function so that x has a strict local maximum in 0 + 2 conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Sorry for the bad title.. I can't describe the exercise just from the title.

Construct a continuous function $$f:]-1, 1[\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ that is differentiable twice with the following properties:

1. $f$ has a strict local maximum in 0
2. There does not exist an $\varepsilon$ > 0 so that $f$ is
   monotonically decreasing in the interval [0, $\varepsilon$]
3. There does not exist an $\varepsilon$ > 0 so that $f$ is
   monotonically increasing in the interval [$-\varepsilon$, 0]

My conditions for this function are 
$$f^{(1)}(0)=0$$
$$f^{(2)}(0)=0$$
$$f^{(2)}(x)\geq0$$ for all $x \neq 0$

I feel like $f^{(2)}(0)=0$ (rather than $f^{(2)}<0$) may be right in this problem but I turn to the community to prove me wrong since I can't get the solution. I've tried various functions $f(x)=x^n$ where $n\geq3$.

Comment: Could you define strict local min/max?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: You're not going to get this with any polynomial. Have you seen functions like $g(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ or $h(x)=x^4\sin(1/x^3)$ (and $0$ at $x=0$, of course) before? Of course, these do not have a strict extremum at the origin, so you'll need to do more ... (You definitely do *not* want a convexity condition, so you do not want the first or second derivative to have constant signs.)

Comment: I know of these functions all right, but I'm not so familiar with them. What exactly do I need to do more? The function needs to be slightly below the maximum (duh) so I need to do something there. But I can't think of anything .. do I need to use the $\varepsilon$ in my function? Kind of like depending on $\varepsilon$ I can make the function turn so it doesn't monotonically increase/decrease in the interval -$\varepsilon$, 0 ; 0 $\varepsilon$

Comment: A further hint would be to modify a concave function like $f(x)=-x^2$ by adding some multiple of one of these and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  look at the graph $f(x) = - x^2$, at $x= 0$ you have a strict local max.   Now consider the sequences $x_n = + \frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n = - \frac{1}{n}$ where both converge to zero.

Now modify the function $f$  on $x_n$ , $y_n$ in smooth way such that $2,3$ are satisfied and still $x=0 $ be strict local max